# Function Not Found in Sanic Server

Tags: python, routes, sanic

In Sanic server, a have a function defined in a file called controller.py with path /views/controller.py. My Sanic app is created in main.py at the root level (/) and can't find this function. The function has the decorator

```
@app.post("/get_x")
```

What do I have to do to make the Sanic app aware of this function's path? I'm getting a 404 error at the moment when calling this function from the browser. I can't seem to find any good documentation or examples on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing something like `import views.controller`?

Comment: No, because the function is being invoked when a call is made using Twilio. The path is defined for the Twilio webhook as name_of_app/get_x. I tried changing it to name_of_app/views/get_x but it didn't make a difference. main.py is not directly calling this function.

Comment: But your route is registered when `@app.post` is executed.  If the interpreter never sees that code, then the route is never registered.

Comment: Tim, appreciate the input. In main.py, I create the Sanic app using app = Sanic(name), and then in other files, I try to retrieve the app using app = Sanic.get_app(name), but it doesn't seem to work. I even tried just app = Sanic.get_app() and it didn't work. This is per Sanic documentation. What am I possibly doing wrong so the app is not being found in other files?

Comment: What is going to make Python look in any other files?  If you don't `import` them, then the code will never be seen!

Comment: Tim, I figured it out. It was the order of the imports that was the problem. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is import ordering.

When you do `Sanic.get_app()`, that will only work *after* the application instance has been created. Therefore, any imports in `main.py` *before* that happens will fail.

You could instead look to expose and build your application's endpoints in factories.

There are a couple methods you could try in my example here: https://github.com/ahopkins/sanicbook/blob/main/application/booktracker/server.py

Or, you could try something like autodiscovery, discussed here: https://sanic.dev/en/guide/how-to/autodiscovery.html